# (BibLaTeX) Same reference in different segments

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a problem with bibliography. I have two separate bib-files and want to print them in two separate bibliographies. I did this with separate `refsegments` There are identical references in both bib-files, but they have different cite-keys. My problem: The identical references are treated as if they were in the same bibliography. Thus, they are printed (in `apa` style) with a letter after the year. This creates a reference in the second bibliography, which is marked with a letter, although there is no other source of the same author in the same year in this segment. In the following, I have an example-code and the result. What I want to have instead is, that these bibliographies are treated separately to get the following result:

> (Einstein, 1905a; Einstein, 1905c)
>
> Bibliography
> Einstein, A. (1905a). The true ab out tree. Annalen der
> Physik, 322 (10), 891–921.
> Einstein, A. (1905b). The true ab out tree
> – 2. Annalen der Physik, 323 (11), 891–921.
>
> (Einstein, 1905)
>
> Bibliography  Einstein, A. (1905). The true ab out tree. Annalen der
> Physik, 322 (10), 891–921.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname1.bib}
    @article{einstein1,
        author = {Albert Einstein},
        title = {the true about tree},
        journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
        year = {1905},
        volume = {322},
        number = {10},
        pages = {891--921}
    }
    @article{einstein2,
        author = {Albert Einstein},
        title = {the true about tree -- 2},
        journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
        year = {1905},
        volume = {323},
        number = {11},
        pages = {891--921}
    }

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname2.bib}
    @article{einstein3,
        author = {Albert Einstein},
        title = {the true about tree},
        journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
        year = {1905},
        volume = {322},
        number = {10},
        pages = {891--921}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname1.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname2.bib}

\begin{document}

    \refsegment
    \parencites{einstein1}{einstein2}
    \begingroup\let\clearpage\relax
    \printbibliography[segment=1]
    \endgroup
    \endrefsegment
    
    \refsegment
    \parencite{einstein3}
    \begingroup\let\clearpage\relax
    \printbibliography[segment=2]
    \endgroup
    \endrefsegment

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need refsection not refsegment if you want to separate them completely

Comment: From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (page 96): "The difference between a `refsection` and a `refsegment` environment is that the former creates **labels which are local to the environment** whereas the latter provides a target for the `segment` filter of `\printbibliography` without affecting the labels. They will be **unique across the entire** document" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Thank you very much! What a simple solution. I did not thought about that.

Answer (score 2):

You need `refsection` not `refsegment` if you want to separate them completely.

`refsection` allows you to filter a bibliography by segment. But this means that you still have only one bibliography with suitable labels, and then can tell biblatex to show only a subset of the entries.

`refsection` on the other side creates two independant bibliographies.